# How to bypass coursera keyboard input verification using JS?

Tags: javascript

I want to bypass coursera keyboard input verification using JS.  Example:

[image: Screenshot 1]

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to generate keyboard event in JS. But you can use keepass app with its feature called auto-type.